# Check if parameter is defined fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to things to check whether the parameter is given in the function or not:

```
var Patient = {
    all : function(pagenumber){
        if(pagenumber == undefined){
            pagenumber = 1;
        }
```

and

```
var Patient = {
    all : function(pagenumber){
         if(pagenumber == null){
             pagenumber = 1;
         }
```

But somehow none of them worked what do I wrong?

Comment: The first should work, unless some jackass has redefined `undefined` in your environment. Does `if(typeof pagenumber === 'undefined'){` work or not?

Comment: This should work: `if(!pagenumber && pagenumber != 0){ pagenumber = 1; }`. I am saying this because sometimes the pagenumber can be `NaN` because this variable sounds to be dealing with numbers.

Comment: Somehow when i call: `console.log(pagenumber);`  it `retunrs o.Event `

Comment: You're using `Patient.all` as an eventhandler function? And the problem is, that `pagenumber` is unexpectedly defined? Please show us how you call `Patient.all`.

Comment: @Teemu oh your right! I have to use `PAtient.all()` !! Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    var Patient = {
       all : function(pagenumber){
              if(typeof pagenumber == 'undefined'){
                  pagenumber = 1;
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

to check if a var is undefined, use the following :

```
var Patient = {
  all : function(pagenumber){
    if(typeof pagenumber == "undefined"){
      pagenumber = 1;
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery:

```
var Patient = {
  all : function(pagenumber){
    if ($.type(pagenumber) === 'undefined')) {
      pagenumber = 1;
    } 
  }
}
```

Or, simplified (since you don't seem to expect a page number '0'):

```
var Patient = {
  all : function(pagenumber){
     pagenumber = pagenumber || 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Trust the jQuery answer to be the first to get upvoted. This is not something that jQuery should be used for.

Comment: I dont understand why but if i print out afer your code: `console.log(pagenumber);` it retunrs o.Event

Comment: @Matt, so why does the convenience method exist?

Comment: @JohnSmith, who is calling that function?

Comment: @Matt, you had me at "Trust the jQuery answer." ;)